# Vue.config.js could not recognize require('webpack')

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

I create a vue3.0 + ts project by CLI, when I add `vue.config.js`, it always have error on `require`

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
```

The errors are

```
module "d:/learning/vue-3-ts-demo/node_modules/webpack/types"

Require statement not part of import statement`.
```

I have install webpack 5.65.0

My packages.json:

```
{
  "name": "vue-3-ts-demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5",
    "webpack": "^5.65.0"
  }
}
```

It is a new vue project  and what is the problem?

Comment: Vue CLI projects use Webpack under the hood, so no need to install it yourself. However, you need to use Vue CLI 5 to use Webpack 5. You'd configure Webpack with the `configureWebpack` or `chainWebpack` options of the config. Why are you trying to import `webpack`?

Comment: @tony19. Thanks.I use  `return new webpack.BannerPlugin(' xxx')` in configureWebpack,so I need to define `const webpack = require('webpack');`.When I remove the webpack package. it has error for ` Cannot find module 'webpack'` when I use `vue-cli-service serve` to run

Comment: @tony19 I find the solution to deal with my original question is that I need to add `'@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 0` in `.eslintrc.js` rules.But the project still could not run with new errors like above comment said

Comment: @tony19. Thanks again,I install the webpack 4.x and it works now.(my vue lic is also 4.x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The errors are
> module "d:/learning/vue-3-ts-demo/node_modules/webpack/types"
>
> Require statement not part of import statement`.

For this error, I delt with it by adding `'@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 0` in`.eslintrc.js`

```
rules: {
'@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 0
}
```

> I have install webpack 5.65.0

Since my vue CLI is 4.5.14, I reinstall webpack version as 4.x too, and it works finally.